# In what scenarios are APIs that don't borrow preferred?

Tags: reference, rust, move-semantics, api-design, borrowing

Rust has the concepts of ownership and borrowing. If a function doesn't borrow its parameter as a reference, the arguments to that function are moved and will be deallocated once they go out of scope.

Take this function:

```
fn build_user(email: String, username: String) -> User {
    User {
        email: email,
        username: username,
    }
}
```

This function can be called as:

```
let email = String::from("foo@example.com");
let username = String::from("username");

let user = build_user(email, username);
```

Since `email` and `username` have been moved, they can no longer be used after `build_user` was called.

This can be fixed by making the API use borrowed references instead.

With that in mind, which scenarios would one always prefer to not use borrowing when designing APIs?

Comment: The function `build_user()` moves the arguments into the struct `User`. If you want to write the same function using borrows, you can't move them into a struct, since you don't own them, so you would have to clone them (or change the definition of `User` to store borrows instead).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Unfortunately, they don't seem to address my question.. If it's too broad, I'm happy to make it more specific. Any suggestions?

I'm just wondering why or when one wants to create an API that doesn't borrow. There has to be cases for that.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as an answer, but rather to point out that your claim that you could just as well use borrows is not true. As a corollary, this very function is an example of a function that would generally take arguments by value, since it needs ownership. If you want further examples, simply take a look at the standard library. Functions that take arguments by value generally can't be written taking borrows instead.

Comment: The reason why I think this is too broad is that answering this question basically means to explain Rust's ownership system. There are already good introductions for this, for example the chapter on ownership in the Rust book.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Yea I'm super new to rust and I'm reading into it at the moment. I did read book about ownership a couple of times now.

If you say there are cases where borrowing isn't possible, then that's fair.

I'll see if I can find an example that demonstrates that.

Comment: Just take a look at [essentially the same function using borrows instead of moved values](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=16ee63852bb46061df9205edf2c3cad5). You need to copy the strings using `to_owned()` to make this work, which is inefficient if you don't need the strings that were passed in anymore. If you write the function accepting values, on the other hand, you are free to pass in clones if you still need the values.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Will have to look into `to_owned()` and lifetimes to make complete sense of this :)

Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This list may not be exhaustive, but there are plenty of times when it's advantageous to choose not to borrow an argument.

### 1. Efficiency with small `Copy` types

If a type is small and implements `Copy`, it is usually more efficient to copy it around, rather than passing pointers. References mean indirection - apart from having to do two steps to get to the data, values behind pointers are less likely to be stored compactly in memory and therefore are slower to copy into CPU caches, for example if you are iterating over them.

### 2. To transfer ownership

When you need data to stick around, but the current owner needs to be cleaned up and go out of scope, you might transfer ownership by moving it somewhere else. For example, you might have a local variable in a function, but move it into a `Box` so that it can live on after the function has returned.

### 3. Method chaining

If a set of methods all consume `self` and return `Self`, you can conveniently chain them together, without needing intermediate local variables. You will often see this approach used for implementing builders. Here is an example taken from the [`derive_builder` crate](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder) documentation:

```
let ch = ChannelBuilder::default()
    .special_info(42u8)
    .token(19124)
    .build()
    .unwrap();
```

### 4. Statically enforcing invariants

Sometimes, you want a value to be consumed by a function to guarantee that it cannot be used again, as a way of enforcing assumptions at the type-level. For example, in the [`futures` crate](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.wait), the `Future::wait` method consumes `self`:

```
fn wait(self) -> Result<Self::Item, Self::Error> 
where
    Self: Sized,
```

This signature is specifically designed to prevent you from calling `wait` twice. The implementation doesn't have to check at runtime to see if the future is already in a waiting state - the compiler just won't allow that situation.

It also gives protection from errors when using method-chained builders. The design statically prevents you from doing things out of order - you can't accidentally set a field on a builder after the object is created because the builder is consumed by its `build` method.

### 5. To make cloning explicit to callers

Some functions need to own their data. This *could* be enforced by accepting a reference and then calling `clone` within the function, but this may not always be ideal because it hides the potentially expensive clone operation from the caller. Accepting the value rather than a reference means that it's up to the caller to clone the value or, if they no longer need it, move it instead.